# Eclipse runtime Dalvik error

Tags: android, eclipse

When i goint to run any program this dialog box is display:

[image]

and in Eclipse these errors display in console:

1. `[2013-02-25 19:05:09 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Target out of range: +0000ffd1`
2. `[2013-02-25 19:05:09 - Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Target out of range: +0000ffd1`

If I remove Android dependencies from project the error disappears but I need a more permanent solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think its kind of a bug, try removing your dependencies (I am referring to added libraries, not the standard-dependencies).
Then clean and rebuild all your projects. Thereafter you should be able to add the removed libraries without errors.

Comment: ya thanks..its already work..
but why this bug is coming every time..for that i also reinstall eclipse but no solution..

Comment: Don't know had the same problem during development my eclipse destroyed itself several times and the above mentioned was the only solution to import my projects into a new enviroment

Comment: when i use Google API v2 their is some library which reside in android dependence without it's not possible to run program so i don't want to remove dependencies..so except remove dependencies  give me other solution for this bug..