# Target out of range

Tags: android

I am getting this error while running my program

```
[2013-06-04 02:02:10 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Target out of range: +0000fffa
[2013-06-04 02:02:10 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Target out of range: +0000fffa
```

Comment: LOL! Rebuild and re-run the project. Sometimes Eclipse messes up with resources and can't convert .class to .dex. Give a restart to Eclipse too.

Comment: I already tried this bt nt working

Comment: Its a bug. Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068521/eclipse-runtime-dalvik-error

Comment: Hey i got solution I removed the android-support-v4 from my libs folder in my project

Comment: Aah! there must be a library-conflict! Great :)